# Run scrot -s from awesome wm

Tags: linux, bash, awesome-wm

When I try to put shortcut on "scrot -s" execution, nothing happenes.

When I use just "scrot" screenshot is taken and saved into necessary directory, but when I use "scrot -s" which is supposed to pop up the selection cursor, nothing happens.
I tried to use both awful.spawn and awful.spawn.with_shell

```
awful.key({ modkey, }, "Print",
            function()
                awful.spawn.with_shell("scrot -s")
            end, { description = "take screenshot", group = 
"launcher" })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind your hotkey to `sleep 0.2 && scrot -s` and it will work. [The problem seems to be](https://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/7ktca8/hotkey_for_scrot_s_not_working_while_scrot_and/), that the window manager does not release the keyboard fast enough for scrot to be able to grab it (to wait for an abort signal).

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution to your problem but it works if using `maim` instead of `scrot`. In addition I'm using `xclip` to automatically copy the image into my clipboard which is very handy.

```lua
awful.key({}, "#107",
  function ()
    awful.util.spawn_with_shell("FILE=" .. os.getenv("HOME") .. "/Media/Screenshots/snapshot-$(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S).png && maim -s --hidecursor $FILE && xclip -selection clipboard $FILE -t image/png")
  end),
```

Comment: I would say that is totally a solution to my problem, switched to maim, works like a charm. Thanks!